# Salary and telephone number transmitted via plain text

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The Job Match Preferences page asks for minimum salary and telephone number, but this information appears to be transmitting back via unencrypted http session.

No, this is not a duplicate. We're talking about sensitive personal financial information on a single page, not general Q&A. This information should be encrypted. There's no excuse.

Comment: While I'm not sure there is a problem here and how big it is (plus I think I read the other day a quote from a team member that SSL for everything on Stack Overflow is not too far away any more), it's not right to close this as a duplicate of the generic "Y u no SSL???" question. As the OP says, the nature of some of the information transmitted through SO jobs is clearly much more sensitive than Q&A, and if SSL for everything isn't incoming, there is no reason not to suggest/consider switching Jobs to it ahead of time.

Comment: Wow. I'm glad I've never gotten to the interview stage with any company via SO Jobs. Now that I think about it, I wonder if I should just delete my Jobs profile altogether...

Comment: @Jack because of a generally very important, but *individually* highly theoretical attack vector that would require access to your machine, your router, the nameservers you use, or Stack Overflow's own server infrastructure? To... find out your telephone number and salary range? Really? Maybe this needs to be fixed, but the idea that *you specifically* were/are at high risk and thus need to shut down your account seems rather silly.

Comment: Desired pay is not really "sensitive personal financial information".

Comment: This is a duplicate in the sense that not using HTTPS for everything isn't much less secure than just using it for the salary/telephone number.

Comment: It's worth noting that SO will be HTTPS everywhere very soon, but I'll give a heads up to the profiles team about this anyway

Comment: @Pekka, any router on the Internet can sniff unencrypted http POST data.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I would be very uncomfortable with people knowing my desired salary and phone number. I'm not sure how you can say it's not sensitive personal info.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I have to agree with DavidG.  No, it is not "what is your current salary?" but most people are sensible when looking for a new position and either really want to get away from a bad employer and thus willing to make a lateral move with regard to pay, or would be looking for a reasonable bump in salary so their current salary could be guesstimated fairly closely.

Comment: @DavidG your phone number is sensitive personal info but your desired salary is not, in and of itself. When tied into a bundle of other personal data, it can be used to strengthen the ability to match a 'profile' to a person, though.

Comment: @TylerH I think perhaps we are getting tied up in legal definitions rather than the more emotive side here. I consider my desired salary to be very personal, though it may not be a good measure to identify me in a data set. I would be very annoyed if that information was given out to anyone without my express permission.

Comment: @DavidG So if someone were to be given a number of "$100,000 as a desired salary" and asked "which user of all the users w/ Jobs profiles does this number belong to?", you think that's reasonably identifiable as yours? I don't. However if someone said "Here is a phone number, 911-867-5309; which Jobs user does it belong to?", you bet that it'd be easy to find who that number belongs to.

Comment: @TylerH No, I'm not suggesting it's personally identifiable, I'm just saying it's personal. That's a very different definition. The point is that a "hacker" in this scenario probably already knows who I am so I'm already identified.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, like I said, when tied to other information that is personally identifiable, it can be used to strengthen the likelihood of a profile match. On its own, though, it's almost entirely anonymous.

Comment: We are talking about the Internet and who knows what legal/illegal data aggressors. If you don't think that thousands of phone numbers with matching desired salary numbers is valuable information, you're not paying attention.

Comment: @TylerH Your password also cannot be used to identify you, would you like to share it here perhaps? :)

Comment: @DavidG sure, if you can provide a way to anonymously reveal it ;-)

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod btw this is a duplicate of the question w/ 3 answers shown in the duplicate banner above.

Comment: @TylerH I don't agree that it's a dupe either (see Pekka's first comment at the top)

Comment: @TylerH, this is definitely not a duplicate of that question. This question is not about general site encryption. Are you saying that if SO was charging credit cards for some service that the CC entry page should not be encrypted because the whole site is in the process of being encrypted? Of course not. This page is a security problem. It needs to be encrypted _immediately_, or those questions need to be removed _immediately_.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod It's about encryption on the site; it doesn't matter where. SSL is already planned and in the works by the team as mentioned there and here by SO devs. The current unencrypted data is not violating any financial regulations like unencrypted credit card data would be.

Comment: @TylerH, so you would put up an unencrypted page to collect credit card numbers, because "SSL is already planned and in the works?" This page is a security issue, right now, today.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod No, did you read my previous comment?

Comment: @TylerH You still seem to be caught up in regulations and legalities. Ultimately, this should be fixed - regardless of whether the entire site is SSL or not. If going full SSL takes 6 months, then it should be looked at. If it's going to happen tomorrow, then who cares.

Comment: @TylerH, yes I read it. Maybe you do not understand how data aggregation works. Small pieces of data are gathered from multiple sources, sometimes hundreds, of sources. The data is matched using different techniques, some more reliable than others. In this case, there is a non-temporal key match to the phone number. Spammers and legitimate advertisers love this information and certainly pay for it. So do identity thieves.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod If you read that I said this data is not governed or even handled the same as credit card data, then why would you ask if I would treat it the same as credit card data? Yes, this should ideally be SSL. No, this does not constitute a severe security vulnerability on the level of unsecured credit card data. Yes, the team is aware of this problem and working on it. Yes the team has already been made aware of this problem and has already said they are working on it.

Comment: @JackManey https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere

Comment: Why would you trust random internet people with sensitive personal information anyway, encryption or no encryption? Simply contact the employer directly, problem solved. The fewer fishy third parties involved, the better. Especially since the whole personnel recruitment branch has a very high quack percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we [moved the entire network to HTTPS](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/), I'm marking this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) :)